# Avoid using a collect on large dataset

Tags: java, apache-spark

We're using Apache Spark for processing. We have several steps where it is necessary to use collect() to to a JavaRDD to a list, but we are wanting to avoid doing this in order to operate on a list. We know we want to avoid this because it brings everything back to the driver. It ends up and we run out of memory because we are processing anywhere from 5million - 200 million records. Here's an example of what we have so far.

```
private InputStream createCSVObject(JavaRDD<Object[]> args) {
        System.out.println("inside createCSVObject");
        try {
            StringBuilder value = new StringBuilder(CHUNK_SIZE);

            args.collect().forEach(i -> {
                value.append(i[0].toString());
                for (int j = 1; j < i.length; ++j) {
                    value.append("," + i[j]);
                }
                value.append("\n");
            });
            System.out.println("Out of createCSVObject for loops");
            byte[] strBytes = value.toString().getBytes();

            InputStream myInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(strBytes);
            return (myInputStream);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println(String.format("ERROR: FileWriterService - writeFile: %s", e.getMessage()));
            return null;
        }
    }
```

I've searched for this over and over across SO and google, and can't come up with anything definitive. Does anyone have any ideas???

Note: the COLLECT at args.collect()

EDIT:

After looking into the proposed answer below we devised a simple proof of concept for it, and what we came up with does one iteration through every 40s. The logic is not complex, why is it so slow?

```
        System.out.println("inside createCSVObject");
        try {
            StringBuilder value = new StringBuilder();
            System.out.println("args length " + args.toLocalIterator().next().length);

             while (args.toLocalIterator().hasNext()) {
                 Object[] objects = args.toLocalIterator().next();
                 System.out.println("Inside iterator");
                 value.append(objects[0].toString());
                 for (int j = 1; j < objects.length; ++j) {
                     value.append("," + objects[j]);
                 }
                 value.append("\n");
             }

            System.out.println("Out of createCSVObject for loops");
            byte[] strBytes = value.toString().getBytes();

            InputStream myInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(strBytes);
            return (myInputStream);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println(String.format("ERROR: FileWriterService - writeFile: %s", e.getMessage()));
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
```

Comment: SparkSQL can be used both to transform data (for instance to take the first element of your object array) and to write your result as CSV either in a distributed way so your job is scalable, or from a single executor.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `JavaRDD.toLocalIterator()` to iterate through the entire RDD on the driver without collecting it all into a list. Instead, it brings each partition over to the driver one at a time, so doesn't use more memory than the size of the largest partition ([documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/api/java/JavaRDDLike.html#toLocalIterator--)).

Obviously, in the exmple you've given, you still have the problem that you're collecting everything into a massive byte array, which will still use quite a lot of memory. Instead, you could write a custom `InputStream` class that wraps an `Iterator` (as returned by `toLocalIterator`), and only buffers one element at a time, calling `next()` on the iterator only when `InputStream.read()` demands more data.

Comment: Oh man that's one point I didn't even think of, the input stream

Comment: I tried this method, toLocalIterator.forEachRemaining, and it still ran out of heap memory.

Comment: What was the stack trace of the OutOfMemory error - what was it trying to do when it failed?

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't give a line number, user31601

Comment: OK, so are you still allocating a `StringBuilder` or `byte[]` somewhere? Is there a chance it could be that? Maybe to experiment, just do `toLocalIterator().forEachRemaining(x -> System.out.println(x));`, and see if that succeeds?

Comment: I made an edit for my question of a partially working proof of concept from your suggestion. It is making only one iteration per 40 seconds. What the??

Comment: `args.toLocalIterator().forEachRemaining(i -> System.out.println("Inside iterator" + i)` Is fast, why would adding the other logic make it so slow??

Comment: Because you're calling `toLocalIterator` again inside your `while` loop. Each time you call that method, spark has to recompute the dataframe. That same rule applies to all "terminal" operations in spark (e.g. `collect`, `show`, `take`, etc). Assign the iterator to a variable, outside the loop, and call `hasNext` and `next` on that variable.

Comment: As a rule in Java, methods whose name begins with "to" mean "I have to do some work to perform this conversion, probably creating a new object in the process". If the RDD just had a local iterator sitting around that you could get access to, the method would be called `getLocalIterator`.

Comment: Ok I changed it back to `toLocalIterator().forEachRemaining(x -> System.out.println(x));` I am testing the logic in this again.

Comment: Yeah, adding in that logic instead of just printing a line and it stalls and never gets past the loop.

Comment: That would suggest that it's running out of memory while allocating the string buffer then. Nothing to do with Spark if that's the case. Time for a rethink, I'd suggest.

Comment: @baitmbarek's comment above is worth consideration. If your aim is just to write to a file, Spark should have built in facilities to do that. I'm not familiar enough with the I/O side to know what they are though.

Comment: Unfortunately we have a business requirement that restricts us to creating the file in memory and never write the file to disk.